How to Fix Overlapping Meshes When Instancing an instance in Blender
I was trying to create a Corinthian Order, and when I was making the mini columns surrounding the large column, which also has leaves around it, I encountered an issue. My process was to create one half of the small leaf, mirror it, and then instance it around the mini column. Finally, I instanced it again around the large column. However, overlapping meshes appeared on the instanced object (the first instance).

